# Oauth 1.0 request signature with content-type other than application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: json, oauth

I am developing a REST API which accepts data in "application/json" and "application/xml" format. I want to use OAuth 1.0 signatures for securing the api calls.
The problem is that OAuth 1.0 clients do not include request body in signature calculation if content-type is not "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", as mentioned in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#section-3.4.1.3

I want to know what is the best solution for this without changing the content-type? As, i want to use OAuth 1.0 clients.

Thanks in advance.